# Enable and disable button by if

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a problem with my js code. I have managed to disable the submit button, if there is no input value, but now I want to enable it again when a value is present.
Thank you very much

```
// submit message
submitButton.addEventListener("click", (e) =>{
  if(userMessage.value = " ") {
    submitButton.setAttribute("disabled", true);
    alert("fill field");

  } if(userMessage.value != " ") {
    submitButton.setAttribute("disabled", false);
   alert("send");
  }
  // prevent default
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: You can't do it that way, because your event listener will not fire after the button is disabled.

Comment: Also, `=` and `==` are different.

Answer (score 1):

You assign a variable instead of condition and second one you are giving single space.

```
submitButton.addEventListener("click", (e) =>{
  if(userMessage.value == "") {
    submitButton.setAttribute("disabled", true);
    alert("fill field");

  } if(userMessage.value != "") {
    submitButton.setAttribute("disabled", false);
   alert("send");
  }
  // prevent default
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: `setAttribute` won't reenable the button again (beside the fact that the click event won't get fired anyway). Instead, you could set `submitButton.disabled = true` (or `false`)

Answer (score 0):

You could add an event listener to the input element and listen for the keyup event. like:

```
inputField.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
    submitButton.setAttribute("disabled", e.target.value === "");
});
```

Comment: This should use `change` instead of `keyup` in order to support autofill.

Comment: also `setAttribute` won't enable the button again. Instead directly set `disabled` (without `setAttribute`)

Answer (score 0):

Maby i dont understand it right but you want to click on a disabled button? To enable it? I dont think that works maby try it when the user types in the input field. So

```
// submit message
InputField.addEventListener("keyup", (e) =>{
  if(e.target.value = "") {
    submitButton.setAttribute("disabled", true);
    alert("fill field");

  } else if(e.target.value != "") {
    submitButton.setAttribute("disabled", false);
    alert("send");
 }
})
```

something like this

Answer (score 0):

add event on input

```
//when page loads to be disabled 
submitButton.setAttribute("disabled", true);

//check when something is changed
userMessage.addEventListener("keyup", (e) =>{
  submitButton.setAttribute("disabled", this.value.trim() == "");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code:

1. You assign the value of `" "` with `=` to the `userMessage`, but you probably intended to check if the value is empty or not. Either use `==` or even better `===`.
2. You are checking against a value that consists out of just one space (`" " !== ""`). Use `.trim()` to actually trim all whitespace around a value.
3. The second if statement is exactly the opposite of the first one and can be written as an `else` statement.
4. You also need to check if the input has changed, so the button would then be enabled again. You could just add an event listener on the `input` event of your text field here and enable/disable the button.
5. Setting the attribute `disabled` to `false` with `setAttribute` won't work here as `setAttribute` converts it into a *String*. So technically it is still trueish. Instead directly set `disabled` on your input element, or use `removeAttribute` to get it enabled again.

Here is an example, using the `input` event for disabling and enabling the button. Note, that the button is not initially disabled. To fix that, I created the `checkIfSet` function, so I can just set it on the `addEventListener` and also just call it to check if the button needs to be disabled or not.

```js
const submitButton = document.querySelector('#submitButton');
const userMessage = document.querySelector('#userMessage');

const checkIfSet = () => {
  const trimmedInput = userMessage.value.trim();
  if (trimmedInput == '') {
    submitButton.disabled = true;
    console.log('disabled');
  } else {
    submitButton.disabled = false;
    console.log('enabled');
  }
};

const submit = (e) => {
  console.log('send');
  e.preventDefault();
}

// submit message
userMessage.addEventListener('input', checkIfSet);
submitButton.addEventListener('click', submit);
checkIfSet();
```

```css
button:disabled {
  background: red;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="userMessage" />
<button id="submitButton">button</button>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your time, and I used your solution and it works. Trim() is very useful, thanks

Comment: I would really like to, but for now, I don´t have enough high reputation...  Any tips how to learn JS or any tips at all? Thank you very much and with the best regards as always

Comment: Oh right :) I totally forgot about that limit. But yes, check out [FreeCodeCamp](https://learn.freecodecamp.org). I think that is a great starting point

Answer (score 0):

Simple and short approach:

1. Disable submit `<button>` by default
2. Attach `oninput` event to `<input/>` which toggles the disabled status of the`<button>`

try

```html
<input type="text" id="userMessage" value="" oninput="this.value == '' ?  document.querySelector('#submitButton').disabled = true : document.querySelector('#submitButton').disabled = false"/>
    
<button disabled id="submitButton">Submit</button>
```